# A formula about contraction

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

$M$ is a compact Kaehler manifold. $f_i(i=1,2,3,4)$ are different real-valued smooth functions on $M$, $\omega$ is a Kaehler form on $M$. My question is that whether the following equation is true:
$$
n(n-1)\int_M\sqrt{-1}\partial f_1\wedge \bar{\partial}f_2\wedge \sqrt{-1}\partial f_3\wedge \bar{\partial}f_4\wedge\omega^{n-2}=\int_M\left(\langle\partial f_1, \bar{\partial} f_2\rangle_\omega\langle\partial f_3, \bar{\partial} f_4\rangle_\omega-\langle\partial f_1, \bar{\partial} f_4\rangle_\omega\langle\partial f_3, \bar{\partial} f_2\rangle_\omega\right)\omega^n.
$$

And if it is not true, what will the left hand side should be equal to?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ture.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&n(n-1)\int_M\sqrt{-1}\partial f_1\wedge \bar{\partial}f_2\wedge \sqrt{-1}\partial f_3\wedge \bar{\partial}f_4\wedge\omega^{n-2}\\
=&n(n-1)\int_M\sum_{i\neq j}(f_1,_if_2,_\bar{i}f_3,_jf_4,_\bar{j}-f_1,_if_2,_\bar{j}f_3,_jf_4,_\bar{i})dz^i\wedge dz^{\bar{i}}\wedge dz^j\wedge dz^{\bar{j}}\wedge \omega^{n-2}\\
=&n(n-1)\int_M\sum_{i, j}(f_1,_if_2,_\bar{i}f_3,_jf_4,_\bar{j}-f_1,_if_2,_\bar{j}f_3,_jf_4,_\bar{i})\omega^{i\bar{i}}\omega^{j\bar{j}}\omega_{i\bar{i}}\omega_{j\bar{j}}dz^i\wedge dz^{\bar{i}}\wedge dz^j\wedge dz^{\bar{j}}\wedge \omega^{n-2}\\
=&\int_M\left(\langle\partial f_1, \bar{\partial} f_2\rangle_\omega\langle\partial f_3, \bar{\partial} f_4\rangle_\omega-\langle\partial f_1, \bar{\partial} f_4\rangle_\omega\langle\partial f_3, \bar{\partial} f_2\rangle_\omega\right)\omega^n.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: It should be noted that this is really a pointwise identity, not an integral identity. The integrands are equal at every point.

Comment: Yes. But I think the following formula may be more useful, for two $(1,1)$-forms $\alpha,\beta$. $$n(n-1)\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\omega^{n-2}=(\text{tr}_\omega\alpha \text{tr}_{\omega}\beta)\omega^n-<\alpha,\beta>_\omega\omega^n.$$